# How can I use CriteriaBuilder to perform a join with more than one condition on it?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have two JPA entity classes (`MyEntity` and `Attribute`) and would like to know how to use `CriteriaBuilder` to perform an inner join with more than one condition on it.

I would like this:

```
SELECT e.id
FROM my_entity e
INNER JOIN my_attribute a
ON e.id = a.event_id
AND a.key = "special-key"   // I want to add this part.
```

Instead of just this:

```
SELECT e.id
FROM my_entity e
INNER JOIN my_attribute a
ON e.id = a.event_id
```

Which I can generate from the following `CriteriaBuilder` code:

```
var cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
var cq = cb.createQuery(Event.class);

var entity = cq.from(MyEntity.class);
entity.join(MyEntity_.attributes);
cq.select(entity);

return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

The classes in question are:

`MyEntity` class:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_attribute_id")
    private List<MyAttribute> attributes;
```

`MyAttribute` class:

```
@Entity
public class MyAttribute {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String key;
    private String value;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MyEntity entity;
```

How can I generate the first snippet with the extra `AND a.key = "special-key"` using `CriteriaBuilder`?

Note that with my example of an inner join I could use the code below but I would like to know how to specifically add the `AND` condition to the join.

```
var cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
var cq = cb.createQuery(Event.class);

var entity = cq.from(MyEntity.class);
entity.join(MyEntity_.attributes);

// Add these three lines.
var join = event.join(MyEntity_.attributes);
var pred = cb.equal(join.get(MyAttribute_.key), "special-key");
cq.where(pred);

cq.select(entity);

return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```